# Synchronization Issue when using ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario where

1. text files are generated dynamically on daily basis. 0 to
   8 per day. size of each file can be small to big. depending on day's
   data.
2. Need to run some checks (business checks , Rules) on them.

I implemented in following way , *Its not behaving as expected , seems i have done something wrong*

For Storing results i have following class , there will be 1 Result class for 1 file

```
public class Result {

    private String fileName;
    private Map<RuleTypes, String> allResult = new HashMap<RuleTypes, String>();

        // setter , getter , constructor .. POJO
}
```

Rules are like

```
public class ValidateRule1 implements Rule {

    private String fileName;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void runRule() {
        System.out.println("Start running ... Rule 1  for "+fileName);
        try {
            Random r = new Random();
            int sleepRandomTime = r.nextInt(15-1) + 1;
            Thread.sleep(sleepRandomTime) ; // simulate rule execution
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("End running ... Rule 1 for "+fileName);

    }

    @Override
    public RuleTypes getRuleName() {
        return RuleTypes.Rule1;
    }

}
```

Rule Factory is like

```
public static Rule getRule(RuleTypes ruleName) {
        Rule result=null;

        switch(ruleName) {

            case Rule1 :
                result = new ValidateRule1(); // todo singleton
                break;

            case Rule2 :
                result = new ValidateRule2(); // todo singleton
                break;

            case Rule3 :
                result = new ValidateRule3(); // todo singleton
                break;
            ...
            }
            }
```

I call Rules in following way , I use RuleFactory to create a rule ( creates singleton objects for Rules )

```
final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Rule> rulesToExecuteForModel = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Rule>();
rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule1));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule2));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule3));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule4));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule5));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule6));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule7));
        rulesToExecuteForModel.add(RuleFactory.getRule(RuleTypes.Rule8));


        // pick 1 file and run all rules for it , different threads can pick up different files concurrently ... dont think will need synchronization here 
        List<File> fileQueue = new LinkedList<File>();
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File1.20140203"));
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File2.20140203"));
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File3.20140203"));
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File4.20140203"));
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File5.20140203"));
        fileQueue.add(new File("../test/files/File6.20140203"));

        // Results Display ... 1 Result obj for 1 File
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result> fileWiseResult = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Result>();
        int maxNumOfFiles = fileQueue.size();  

        // TODO : how can i exploit the fact that this program runs on 8 core machine ? does 1 thread correspond to 1 CPU ? i kept 8 here because it will run on 8 core machine
        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        final ExecutorCompletionService<Result> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(pool);

        for (final File file : fileQueue) {
            System.out.println("picked file "+file.getName()+" running ALL rules for it");
            final Future<Result> contentFuture = completionService.submit(new Callable<Result>() {
                @Override
                public Result call() throws Exception {
                    Result r = new Result(); // 1 file 1 Result object
                    r.setFileName(file.getName());
                    Iterator<Rule> itr=rulesToExecuteForModel.iterator();
                    // sequentially run different rules for same file
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        Rule currentRule  = itr.next();
                        currentRule.setFileName(file.getName());
                        currentRule.runRule();
                        // take fileName / File as parameter , String result for  currentFile and currentRule
                        r.getFileResult().put(currentRule.getRuleName(), "result for "+currentRule.getRuleName().toString());
                    }
                    return r; 
                }
            });
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <maxNumOfFiles; ++i) {
        Future<Result> future;
        try {
            future = completionService.take();
            Result currentResult=null;
            try {
                currentResult = future.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Result for file ["+currentResult.getFileName()+"] is ["+currentResult.getFileResult()+"]");
            fileWiseResult.add(currentResult);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output is like

```
picked file File1.20140203 running rules for it
Start running ... Rule 1  for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 1 for File1.20140203

E
Start running ... Rule 2 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 2 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 2 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 3 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 3 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 4 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 4 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 4 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 5 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 5 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 5 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 5 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 5 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 6 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 6 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 6 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 7 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 7 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 7 for File1.20140203

Start running ... Rule 8 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 8 for File1.20140203
End running ... Rule 8 for File1.20140203
Result for file [File1.20140203] is [{Rule2=result for Rule2, Rule5=result for Rule5, Rule1=result for Rule1, Rule6=result for Rule6, Rule4=result for Rule4, Rule7=result for Rule7, Rule3=result for Rule3, Rule8=result for Rule8}]
```

I was **expecting ONE statement like** "Start Running...Rule 2 for File1.20140203" **and ONE LIKE** "End running ... Rule 2 for File1.20140203"

But as seen in output , the number of Times "End " > number of Times "Start "

Also i observe

```
Start running ... Rule1 for File5.20140203
Start running ... Rule1 for File6.20140203
Start running ... Rule1 for File6.20140203
Start running ... Rule1 for File4.20140203
Start running ... Rule1 for File5.20140203
Start running ... Rule1 for File4.20140203
```

I was expecting 6 unique file names in above log message

**First Ques : What am i doing wrong ? how can i correct it ?**

**Second question (optimization .. not actual problem)** This program will run on an 8 core machine .... if i keep a pool size of 8 does it mean 8 threads will run parallely ... one each core ... is there a way i can ensure this ??

Comment: Doesn't look like you are using the `ExecutorCompletionService` at all.  Typically you do not need to manage the `Future`s when you use a ECS.

Comment: thanks Gray for quick response ..... i dont manage the Futrure object now ( modified the code in question , still same issue ) ... ALSO i highlighted the output (hope u can see the number of END > number of start) .... Let me know if i need to clarify further

Comment: I think the issue is with Syncronization of Rules , my rules dont implement Runnable/Callable ... when i monitor the output log closely then i see that "Start running ... Rule 1 for File1.20140203" I was expecting this message for rule1 for 6 DIFFERENT files .... but i notice the file names are repeated ( adding same to question )

Comment: Sorry my mistake , modified the ques again ... added code for ValidateRule1 ... which has Start , End Messages , Let me know if any doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as seen in output , the number of Times "End " > number of Times "Start "

Your bug is on this line:

> currentRule.setFileName(file.getName());

Multiple threads are using the same collection of rules.  The rules therefore should not have any persistent state.  You should pass in the file name with every rule method call.

You should change your `runRule()` method to take a `fileName` argument and *not* have one as a field to your rule classes.

> This program will run on an 8 core machine .... if i keep a pool size of 8 does it mean 8 threads will run parallely ... one each core ... is there a way i can ensure this ??

They should yes but there is no way to ensure it.  Other processes running on the OS will need to be serviced as well.  It also depends on how much IO and other blocking operations are happening in your application as to whether they all run in parallel.  The right thing to do is to vary the number of threads in the pool until you get the optimal speed of your application.

Comment: is there a way i can write test cases for testing "syncronization" and not the rule validation logic ... I want a test case that verifies that there is no syncronization issue !!

Comment: That is extremely hard @Lav.  You can write tests that exercise the code but they will never be able to "verify" it for sure.  Good code review is the best practice unfortunately.  Be very careful of shared objects.